# Find error location in Installshield

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, filepath

My guess is "there is no way" but figured I'd ask.  There is a file path in a msi project that I am working.  This file path points to a location other than where I want to store the file so I want to change the path.  The problem is that I have been unable to find where this path is being defined in the msi project.  Is there a way to search for the file definition or use the error to find where this file path is?

Answer (score 1):

In **Installshield** there is a tab called "[**Path Variables**](http://shieldmaster.wordpress.com/2007/06/21/path-variables-and-project-organization/)". This view contains "location macros" defining locations from which files are included.

The idea is that the "location macro" allows whole folders to be moved without breaking the path:

- **File on disk**: C:\Test Files\My Application\Test.exe
- **Path macro**: PATH_TO_SOURCE_FILES = C:\Test Files\My Application
- **Path defined in Installshield's tables**: `<PATH_TO_SOURCE_FILES>\Test.exe`
- You can now move the whole folder and update the path specified by PATH_TO_SOURCE_FILES and no redefinition of the path elsewhere in the setup is needed.

See the blog I linked to above: [**Path Variables and Project Organization**](http://shieldmaster.wordpress.com/2007/06/21/path-variables-and-project-organization/)

I guess a path in the Path View was broken, and you have now added a direct path by going to the Direct view and browsing to a path. Unless Installshield has translated the path by substituting part of it with a location macro - and the tool generally does this.

**Direct Editor** shows pretty much the "raw tables" of an MSI, and you should not work in this view unless you are sure of what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately the path was not located in path tables.  It had been given an half and half job where it dynamically referred to the project directory but then a hard coded path past there.  I was able to fix it and make it dynamic.  Good lesson on why to use the path variables!

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure how helpful outside of this instance this information will be, but I finally solved the problem.  I went into "Direct Editor" which is in the "Additional Tools" folder in the IDE.  I went down the list of tables until I found the Binary table (The error did specifically mention the Binary table).  In this table I was able to find that one of the paths was the path I was looking for.  I was able to then edit that path and get the build to work.

There is a problem with this solution; I have no idea if this file is still necessary.  My guess is that the file is not necessary, and that at this point it is being packed simply because it exists.  Later testing will tell.